# Select a Contact From a Table and Grab Phone Number

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, javascript-remoting

I have an issue that I think I am over complicating. I have a table of Contacts. **I need to select a Contact and grab their mobile phone number.** I have tried everything from visualforce remoting to jQuery to sforce.apex.execute. I don't want to set the checkbox to a custom field value of Contact. Am I over complicating this? Is there a simple way to check a checkbox and grab the user data? `Text()` was the function I was using for my apex remoting attempts.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="6" title="Select Contacts: ">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="con">
                <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox id="looped" onclick="uncheckOthers(this);" /></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!con.Name}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Mobile Number" value="{!con.MobilePhone}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Opted-In"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.SMS_Opt_In__c}" disabled="true"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Opted-Out"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.SMS_Opt_Out__c}" disabled="true"/></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Select" onClick="text()"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a function and during `onclick` pass mobilePhone value

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="looped" onclick="selectContact(this, '{!con.MobilePhone}');" />
```

Comment: So much easier. Thank you! I was banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: that's why members are here.